# Convert varchar to datetime and add seconds

Tags: sql-server, datetime, varchar, seconds, sql-convert

I have two columns `startDate` (`160812` - year, month, day) and `startTime` (`112345` - hour, mimutes, seconts) with a `varchar` datatype my target is concatenate them and convert them into **datetime**. And I should added to them other column (`duration - int`)

I tried something like this:

```
WITH [A] AS 
(
    SELECT (startDate + startTime) AS time1
    FROM [Date] 
 )
SELECT 
    CONVERT(datetime, A.time1, 20)
FROM 
    [A]
```

however I get an error message:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any better ideas to try?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select (convert(datetime, startDate, 12) + 
        convert(time, stuff(stuff(startTime, 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':')))
       ) as dt
```